# fop two column, positioning external graphic at the top (XSL-FO)

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I want to position image at the top of page, e.g. I have 3 to 4 image at different places. I would like to position it at the top of pages (spaning all the width)instead getting into middle,even if the  containing text ends in the middle. Is it possible with fop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but you have to be more specific what you actually want. And provide a code example of what you have tried so far.